# in Selenium python ,by running these codes, the web page opens but closes very quickly. What is the cause of this and how can I fix it?

Tags: python, variables, selenium-webdriver, error-handling

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from time import sleep

```
service = Service(executable_path = r'D:\webdriver\chromedriver.exe')      
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service)     
driver.get(r'https://translate.google.com/')      
driver.current_url

#and my second problem: When I write some executable code in this program (like the last line) 
#it shows me such an error:

#[848:12760:0618/223610.181:ERROR:ssl_client_socket_impl.cc(978)] handshake failed; returned 
#-1,SSL error code 1, net_error -101
```

#How can I fix it??